# How to customize the title and tooltip in ux-chartjs?

Tags: symfony, chart.js

I made a chart with Symfony UX and chartJs. Everything works but when I want to customize it, it become  a problem and I can't find a good docs for that.
My chart is done and now I want to customize the tooltip and the title, I did like that :

```php
$chart->setOptions([
            'responsive' => true,
            'title' => [
                'display' => true,
                'text' => 'test',
                'color' => '#ce1111',
            ],
            'tooltips' => [
                'backgroundColor' => '#ce1111',
                'titleColor' => '#000'
            ]
        ]);
```

For the `title`, it displays 'test' but the color doesn't work even if I replace it with `titleColor`.
For `tooltips` the `backgroundColor` works but not the `titleColor`.
Anyone has already solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, sorry  for the question but the docs is different. I post here how I dit it :

```php
$chart->setOptions([

            'responsive' => true,
            'title' => [
                'display' => true,
                'text' => strtoupper('test'),
                'fontColor' => '#ce1111',
                'fontSize' => 16
                //'padding' => 50
            ],
            'tooltips' => [
                'backgroundColor' => '#fff',
                'bodyFontColor' => '#000',
                'bodyFontSize' => 16,
            ],
            'legend' => [
                'labels' => [
                    'fontColor' => "#ce1111",
                    'fontSize' => 16
                ]
            ]

        ]);
```

Comment: Thx that works. I tried to do the same with a callback in a tooltip but I failed. It's harder to work with chartjs UX than pure chartJs